# Redirect in observer on server not working

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, redirect

I have created an observer model to redirect the checkout page after successful order to another form. The Redirection code I have applied is working on my localhost but when I tried the same code on server it is giving the error :

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:140:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/local/Mage/Cms/Block/Eblock.php, line 2";i:1;s:2101:"#0 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
 #1 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://remarkab...', 302)
 #2 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/local/Dataman/OrderInfo/Model/Observer.php(24): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://remarkab...')
 #3 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Dataman_OrderInfo_Model_Observer->getSuccessOrderInfo(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
 #4 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Dataman_OrderInfo_Model_Observer), 'getSuccessOrder...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
 #5 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('checkout_onepag...', Array)
 #6 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(294): Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepag...', Array)
 #7 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->successAction()
 #8 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('success')
 #9 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #10 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #11 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #12 /home1/remarkc4/public_html/restauranttechpros/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:55:"/restauranttechpros/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/";s:11:"script_name";s:29:"/restauranttechpros/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Here is my code of observer:

```
 <?php 
 class Dataman_OrderInfo_Model_Observer
 {
 public function getSuccessOrderInfo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 {
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

    if (!is_array($orderIds) || (!array_key_exists(0, $orderIds))) 
    {
        return;
    }

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds[0]);
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $itemcount=count($items);        
    $ids=array();
    foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
    {            
        $ids[]=$item->getProductId();        
    }        

    if(in_array('1207',$ids))
    {            
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customerticket'))->sendResponse();
        exit();
    }

    return true;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Please help me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check these articles, but i think that the sendResponse is causing the error message :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236912/magento-redirect-from-observer-that-always-works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749005/magento-redirect-customer-from-observer-method
http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/07/21/magento-redirect-from-observer/

Than look at the server configuration (php.ini) and maybe your cookie configuration.
Also check your general web configuration http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/web

These article lists the step required to move a production to development server. 
http://markshust.com/comment/117.
http://www.islbd.com/resources/item/24-how-to-move-magento-from-one-server-to-another.html
 In your case is the other way around, but the steps are the same. In essence you need to update some config values. Pay attention to urls and cookies. I think that they are causing your headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have googled a lot from last two days but nothing work for me. I don't know what is the issue on the server as the same code is working absolutely fine on my localhost.

Comment: I have followed the same steps for installation. Can you tell me any other way through which I can redirect to my desired page after order success?

Comment: For which event is your observer registered?

Comment: It is for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Comment: I just want to check a particular product in the cart and if the order is made with that product then redirect it to some specific page instead of Success page. How can I do this?

Comment: Try this way of redirect:http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230608/

Comment: Not working this way also. I am totally unable to understand whats happening.

Comment: Do you have some kind of opcode cache like APC enabled?

Answer (score 0):

try the below code in if condition for redirection, Hope so this will work,

```
if(in_array('1207',$ids))
{
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customerticket'));
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is also not working.

Comment: check for whitespace at the end of the file(observer.php), if present remove than remove it.

Comment: I also checked that. There is no space.